# How to count the occurrence of a given object in a list?

Tags: java

for eg I have a list and a class called Sample: 
The list is :

```
List<Object> testList = new ArrayList<>();
testList.add("a");
testList.add("b");
testList.add(new Sample());
testList.add(new Sample());
```

How can I get the count of occurrences of Object Sample from the list?

Answer (score 2):

You can use java 8 stream:

```
sampleCount = testList.stream().filter(o -> o instanceof Sample).count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looping through the elements and testing to see if the object is an instance of the `Sample` class via:

```
int count = 0;
for (final Object o : testList) {
    if (o instanceof Sample) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works , is there any other way which we can use for eg : using Collections.frequency() ?

Comment: I tried that but doesn't work out..there is no easy go for this i guess

Comment: My response shows you a more visual counting solution, whereas you may be interested in sharonbn's solution if you understand the mechanics of the one-liner.

Comment: If you want to use frequency, you need override `equals` and `hashCode` in the `Sample` class. The problem with @Confiqure's comment is that it counts the frequency of that exact object. And it this case it will compare references.